# Workload Identity Federation: How to permanently delete a pool/provider?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, workload-identity

We're deploying workload identity pools and we wanted to destroy then recreate a pool with the same name. However, [GCP won't allow you to create a new workload identity pool with the same name until 30 days after you delete a pool](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/manage-workload-identity-pools-providers#delete-pool).

**Is there any way we can force the permanent deletion of the pool so we can recreate it?**

For context, we're deploying this via Terraform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello,
 
There is no force way for deletion while waiting for the 30 days grace period to finish. What can be recommended is to wait to finish the grace period or use a different name for the pool.

Answer (score 1):

With terraform you can use same workload identity pool, import the workload identity pool add it in your terraform config, before everything in your module, and refresh state.

This will make you use same workload identity pool name.